# How to change the name of 'name' column in the 'users' table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have a Laravel app with the `users` table. I want it (the table) to have `username` column instead of `name` column, i.e. structure like this:

```
|  id |  username  |        email       |    password   | ...etc. |
| --- | ---------- | ------------------ | ------------- | ------- |
|  1  | Username 1 | email1@example.net | xEvehgv#52... |   ...   |
|  2  | Username 2 | email2@example.net | dkjbg#%R!D... |   ...   |
```

How can I do this with the help of Laravel 9 without having problems with form data validation and third-party packages? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Change the migration in `database/migrations` that creates the user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the answer to my question [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#customizing-the-validation-attributes). Thank you, everyone, for paying attention to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Note: changing the column `name` in the `users` table is not a good idea because a lot of packages use the default name of the table. Instead, you can add a new column with your customer name.

For example:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Otherwise, you can achieve this by going to `database/migrations/_create_users_table.php`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And also you have to run migrations

```
php artisan migrate
```

or execute this command:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Comment: nice answer , I think best if you start your answer with the  **note**

Comment: nice point i will update my answer

Comment: I've read the note, but here is my goal. When a validation error occurs, a toast is displayed. For example, when the username is empty, 'The name field is required' toast is shown, but I want the toast text to be  'The username field is required'. That's all I want. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post a new question and add your codes so I can see where the problem is and also share the link of the question in here so it will be easy for me to find it

Comment: I think I've already noticed my mistake, I don't need to post a new question, thank you for helping.

Comment: great it's always good to find the problem by your own

Comment: @MohammadEdrisRaufi, unfortunately, I didn't actually find the mistake. OK, here is the essence of the problem. I need to override default column names in `users` table without having problems with form data validation and third-party packages. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the problem that you have is with validation even if you change the column name you have to change the validation also it is better to add a new column and validation for it

Comment: OK, @MohammadEdrisRaufi, but even this won't solve possible problems with third-party packages. I guess I'll just leave it as is.